# Append millions of JSON files into a single file efficiently

Tags: python, json, jq, large-data

I have millions of json files which I need to append to a single json file as a list of json dicts:

Each json file contains following dict:

```
{
  "finent": "abc",
  "findeplabel": "lbl",
}
```

Should be combined into a single json file as a list of dicts:

```
[{
  "finent": "abc",
  "findeplabel": "lbl",
},
{
  "finent": "abc",
  "findeplabel": "lbl",
}...]
```

The problem with using "cat" command etc is that the input files are huge in number and the final file size can be >8GB.

inefficient version: `cat *.json|replace "}\n{" "},{"`
So what is the most efficient way to merge the json files ideally concurrently for more efficiency?

Comment: Why would you call `cat` inefficient? What part(s) of the operation that it does here (concatenating one file at the end of another) can be done more efficient, in your opinion? (Also: why the Python tag?)

Comment: @RadLexus going at the lower levels and just concatenating files without copying it to a new file descriptior

Comment: also the operation to add comma "," after emitting each file output can be introduced to make it more efficient saving later passes.

Comment: replace is a python program for replacement of strings

Comment: "going at the lower levels and just concatenating files without copying it to a new file descriptior" what Unix kernel calls would that "low level" even be? I don't see how that'd work at all. And concurrency is rather pointless when the whole operation is IO bound.

Comment: @Voo I dont know hence the question. Also you can answer if its possible to do it efficiently with cat alone?

Answer (score 1):

The following script (slurp.sh) exemplifies a direct approach using bash.
It can easily be modified depending on how the relevant JSON files are to be specified.

I suspect that it would take much longer to develop and test a more complex solution than doing so will save in execution time, but if you want to experiment with parallelism, you might like to look into using the GNU `parallel` command.

I've tested and benchmarked the script using 100,000 trivial .json files
in a single directory.  On my 6 year old computer, the following invocation takes about 8 minutes (wall clock time),
of which the jq invocation takes about 0.2 sec.

```
$ ./slurp.sh | jq length
100000
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script slurps the contents of all the .json files in the pwd
ls | grep .json | nl | while read i f
  do
    if [ $i = 1 ] ; then
      echo "["
    else
      echo ","
    fi
      cat $f
  done
echo "]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak about its efficiency, but with jq, it's just a matter of slurping all files together:

```
jq -s '.' *.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an excellent efficient way of doing it:

```
 ls |xargs -n 10000 -P 8 jq -s '.' >>../jsonparsed
```

This spawn 8 concurrent processes each having 10k arguments and writes to a single jsonfile jsonparsed

Comment: How do you guarantee that the files don't end up mixed? Is `jq` able to access the same file without ending up with mixed contents or erroring out because it is locked for write access? How can `jq` be faster then cat when it also interprets the contents of the json file?

Comment: @RedX order does not matter

Comment: also can replace jq with cat for better speed

Comment: @stackit - Unfortunately, using xargs like this won't do what you say you want.

Comment: @peak so how to do what I want?